# Why isnt lombok @sl4j annotation using or detecting logback.groovy under resources folder?

Tags: java, groovy, logback

I have a Java application I am using the Lombok @Sl4f annotation with logback. So far I have an issue using logback.groovy it doesn't create an output logfile.

I tried using the exact equivalent logback.xml and everything works fine. However I need to use logback.groovy for this project. Please see the working logback.xml below as well as the logback.groovy which doesn't work.

FYI - I notice no errors.

logback.groovy

```
def byDay = timestamp("ddMMyyyy'-'HHmmss")
appender("STDOUT", ConsoleAppender) {
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  }
}
appender("FILE", FileAppender) {
  file = "log-${byDay}.log"
  append = true
  encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
    pattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
  }
}
root(INFO, ["FILE", "STDOUT"])
logger("com.tester.space.deriver.xprogram", DEBUG, ["FILE", "STDOUT"], false)
```

logback.xml

```
<timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'-'HHmmss"></timestamp>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>log-${byDay}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.tester.space.deriver.xprogram" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
```

So why doesn't the logback.groovy produce the output log file like logback.xml?

Comment: What happens when you run with `-Dlogback.debug=true` option? Does it print anything interesting in the very start e.g. invalid configuration resources?

Comment: Did you tried to specify it explicitly with `-DLogback.configurationFile=/path/to/logback.groovy`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I added -Dlogback.debug=true to the program VM args and I don't see anything different. Program starts up as normal and writes log lines to the console only.

Comment: @talex Do I need to do this? The logback,.groovy is under my resources folder

Comment: @TheDon2019 You don't, but it will help to debug the problem. There is two option here: system can't find configuration file or it can't process it. If it is former, then specifying path explicitly will solve the problem.

Comment: @talex I did just try this and it makes no difference.

Comment: @TheDon2019 this mean it unable to process configuration. Do you have `groovy-all` in your dependencies?

Comment: @talex I have groovy-all 2.5.5 in my dependencies